# Call javascript file and function, when an image is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run an external script that I cannot edit. Currently I am calling upon the script when the page loads. This slows my site down. I would like to instead call the javascript file and run the function when it is clicked. I made it a little faster by calling the function, when clicked. However, it still calls the javascript file because I don't know how to make it call that and the function, when clicked. I spent a few hours reading and trying to find a similar request on Google with no success.

Below you will see what I have came up with so far.

```
<div id="myFunctionID" style="background: url('http://example.com/button.png') repeat
 scroll 0 0 transparent; width: 100px; height: 50px; cursor: pointer; position:fixed; 
 bottom:0; left:0;">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://externalScript.js"></script>
```

Please help me load the `JS` file and the `myFunctionID`, when the button image is clicked.

Comment: You will have to have your own `.js` file with a click handler that dynamically loads the `externalScript.js` and calls the appropriate function within it.

Comment: studying click handler now. Will post how I did it, if I can figure it out. Thanks

Comment: It is a bad idea to load the JS file each time the image button is clicked.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to load the JS file, when a button is clicked. Only 1 out of 10,000 hits actually use the plugin. The plugin slows down my site; 76/100 pagespeed with the plugin and 84/100 without it per Google.

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript (Quoted from [JavaScript - function to load external JS files is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278492/javascript-function-to-load-external-js-files-is-needed))

```
function loadScript(url, callback){

    var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    if (script.readyState){  //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        script.onload = function(){
            callback();
        };
    }

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Using jquery

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.getScript("pathto/external.js");
});
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that the question doesn't state the tag jquery. Also I would recommend if you want to use this, using the [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function.

Comment: Seems like more is going on than needed. I will try to tackle the jQuery one tomorrow. Never got anything to work right for me, but it is due to my own JS ignorance.

Comment: Neither the JS nor the jquery worked for me. I have no errors in the console, but when clicking it doesn't load the external script. I also changed the ID of my background img div to be button. I tried with and without the # in front on the jquery too.