# jquery find and replace string in script code then run this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unfortunately I have to use VPN to visit google, including recapcha. Some chrome extensions can redirect those to recaptcha.net, otherwise I won't see captcha at all.....works in most cases, but sometimes not. Now I got this site, the source code shows replacement did not happen. 
It's like:

```
<div class="gglcptch gglcptch_v3"><input type="hidden" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response"> <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LesAYIUAAAAAMj2s2eUJfWEJNiAZTdeGONG5r5w"></script>
                            <script>
                              grecaptcha.ready(function() {
                                  grecaptcha.execute('6LesAYIUAAAAAMj2s2eUJfWEJNiAZTdeGONG5r5w', {action: 'BWS_reCaptcha'}).then(function(token) {
                                    document.querySelectorAll( "#g-recaptcha-response" ).forEach( elem => ( elem.value = token ) );
                                  });
                              });
                             </script></div>
```

So I essembled this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.gglcptch gglcptch_v3').html(function(index,html){
    return html.replace(/www\.google\.com\/recaptcha\//g,'recaptcha.net/recaptcha/');
});


});
```

Chrome dev did not show error, but still replacement not happening.
So my guess is the sequence? when document.ready, script already done running?
What should I do？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Your selector is wrong. Should be like the below one:**

```
$('.gglcptch.gglcptch_v3').html(
   // ... your function
)
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.gglcptch.gglcptch_v3').html(function(index,html){
    return html.replace(/www\.google\.com\/recaptcha\//g,'recaptcha.net/recaptcha/');
});

console.log($('.gglcptch.gglcptch_v3 script').attr('src'))

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gglcptch gglcptch_v3"><input type="hidden" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response"> <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LesAYIUAAAAAMj2s2eUJfWEJNiAZTdeGONG5r5w"></script>
                            <script>
                              grecaptcha.ready(function() {
                                  grecaptcha.execute('6LesAYIUAAAAAMj2s2eUJfWEJNiAZTdeGONG5r5w', {action: 'BWS_reCaptcha'}).then(function(token) {
                                    document.querySelectorAll( "#g-recaptcha-response" ).forEach( elem => ( elem.value = token ) );
                                  });
                              });
                             </script></div>
```

**2. But this won't replace google recaptcha to any other external source.**

> when document.ready, script already done running?

The answer is: Yes.

**3. You should load external script(from recaptcha.net or so).**
    See e.g. this link: [JavaScript - function to load external JS files is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278492/javascript-function-to-load-external-js-files-is-needed)

Comment: Thank you so much. This works! Though I'm still having problem putting it to code (which I'll open another question), I can login now in Chrome Dev - 1st step is $.getScript, 2nd step is grecaptcha.ready(function()...2nd step I got "undefined" but I can login now.